# Does every city have a "death watch"?

Tags: simcity-2013

It annoys me to no end that water seems to be a finite resource in every city, and even when importing from other cities it seems to not be enough or stop for no reason after a while. Is there an inherent game mechanic in SimCity forcing people to not play a single city for too long?

Comment: RE: water, see this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107735/does-the-water-table-replenish