# Ground getting polluted by itself?

Tags: simcity-2013

After logging in to the game, I suddenly found out most of my city ground is getting poluted.

The issue is that, I am running 'green' town, and there was no polution over many days of gameplay, and suddenly lots of it being generated.

Also the polution is in very interesting 'mini squares', please look on screenshots as reference.

Question: Why is my city getting polluted? That makes little sense and completely ruined my city.
[image: Random pollution]

More pictures of the situation (fullscreen):

1. [Overall ground pollution overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_03_07_SimCity_.png)
2. [Air pollution overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_07_23_SimCity_.png) (Bare in mind the Garbage dump would not give me any trouble for the last IRL week of playing this city)
3. [Germs overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_08_55_SimCity_.png) (Obviously, as the ground is all poluted)
4. [Sewage overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_13_29_SimCity_.png)
5. [Water pollution overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_15_49_24_SimCity_.png) (Notice the stripes!)
6. [Garbage overlay](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_25_19_SimCity_.png) (They manage to collect all garbage by around 10PM each day)

All that is happening enormously fast, there was 0 pollution '2 in-game days' ago, and it it keeps growing. I also have filled all the spaces with trees, but the generated pollution is if all those buildings were Processors Factories.

Comment: Seeing as I haven't given enough information, I will add more information in a moment. If it was Air pollution, I would see it on 'Air pollution' overlay, right?

Comment: you should, yes

Comment: Please see more information in the Question body.

Comment: @kalina - Added sewage map. I afraid it is not the case.

Comment: Interesting, try planting trees from the Nature list (tree with a green arrow pointing down) in the areas with high ground pollution. Also can you post up a garbage map?

Comment: @kalina Posting in a moment. As I mentioned, I have filled them with trees already. What scares me is that the city pollution is increasing incredibly fast, feels more like a bug to be honest.

Comment: If you click on the big buildings that are in the middle of the region suddenly getting polluted, are they unhappy about anything in particular? If there was a brief failure in the garbage or sewage system they'll be "unhappy" about the "way the garbage was piled up" or similar

Comment: @kalina I looked it up firstly, they were unhappy of polluted water. Which is even strangier, and I will post the water pollution screenshot too. Noticing, I have replaced the pumps to the Filtered ones. But what is insane, is why the water become polluted in the first place and the pattern of pollution is insane. (straight lines, see screenshot)

Comment: It looks like your sewage system is next to your water pump in the first screenshot, if you're not filtering your water this will spread pollution all over your city (and lots of germs)

Comment: @kalina My sewage is treated and cleaned. The water overlay shows the water is clear there. Also if it was the case, I would get a warning of polluted water, as I got with a water pump below (replaced it to Filtered pumps)

Comment: Replacing them after the fact won't instantly clean up the water - it will take time. What you'll want to do is keep planting trees in the affected areas until the ground pollution has been sorted and then you should be back to running a clean city.

Comment: @kalina That is not explaining the speed of pollution spreading. Look at this poor house: http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_16_30_15_SimCity_.png '4' ingame days before it was fine

Comment: In the water map screenshot, it still looks like you're using standard water pumps, was this taken before you replaced them?

Comment: Okay, my city got ruined in mysterious manner. Before I would have dozen of cities full of Factories, Electornics Factories, and would  gently tackle it with all the suggestions made here. But in this case, I am doing everything suggested, and the ground is being polluted like if I had all that sewage dumped in the city centre without treating.

Comment: Yeah I just loaded up one of my cities as a point of reference, and I have my water pumps next to an ore refinery, which as you can imagine means it's pumping dirty water around, but every one of my pumps is a filtration pump so no germs ever get into the system and the ground pollution is isolated under the buildings creating the pollution

Comment: @kalina That is an interesting version. Are you sure that pumping after sewage is treated being still dangerous? I understand if sewage was not treated, but it is.. and I had this setup lasting several IRL days. Then suddenly everything changed as I loaded the game this evening.

Comment: If you pump anything other than clean surface water without a filtration pump, you will be pumping whatever is in the water along with it. If you're using a standard pump to pump anything but the brightest of blue water on the water table, this will result in the spread of  ground pollution. General rule: always use filtration pumps.

Comment: @kalina It was clean, though I am not able to prove it at this stage. I also doubt polluted water could make my city centre ground pollution going from 0 to insane values in few in-game days. It would in-game weeks for the same to happen with heavy-industry city. Thank you for your support, I understand that you are not a game developer and cannot confirm whether it is a bug, a hidden mechanism, or anything else. I will vote you up and wait for a while, if others got any other versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your water map, it looks like you've been pumping sewage through your water system:

[water map http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_15_49_24_SimCity_.png](http://josh.c-servers.com/web/2013_11_08_15_49_24_SimCity_.png)

While placing your water pumps and sewage filtering system next to each other [is the way to ensure you don't run out of water](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107735/52800), you must replace all of your water pumps with filtration pumps, otherwise you'll just be pumping sewage around your city, which will not only result in massive ground pollution but also make your sims seriously ill.

Comment: Thank you, I know all that things, been playing for several months. This one is something I never came across. Please bare with me, I will post full-size screenshots of all my city stats so that you can judge on what might be an issue